# Compare temporal variables in virtuoso

Tags: sparql, virtuoso

I work on virtuoso and get a problem with comparing temporal variables

My data is in a ttl file, very simple, as follows:

```
@prefix attr: <http://my.com/attr_> .
@prefix : <http://my.com/> .
@prefix xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#> .

:t99255 attr:ts "2007-01-14 20:01:55"^^xsd:dateTime .
:t99255 attr:te "2008-10-04 14:33:09"^^xsd:dateTime .
:t99257 attr:ts "2009-05-02 04:35:11"^^xsd:dateTime .
:t99257 attr:te "2099-12-31 15:59:59"^^xsd:dateTime .
```

Then I load it into a graph called test. I run the query "sparql select * from  where {?s ?p ?o};" and get above 4 records.

However, when I run following query:

```
sparql
PREFIX  :       <http://my.com/>
PREFIX  attr:   <http://my.com/attr_>
PREFIX  xsd:    <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>

SELECT ?triple_0 ?t_ts ?t_te
FROM <gstest>
WHERE {
    ?triple_0 attr:ts ?t_ts .
    ?triple_0 attr:te ?t_te .
    FILTER ( ?t_ts < ?t_te )
};
```

I got only one result only one result "t99255". I guess that the problem is that "2099-12-31 15:59:59" is not a valid dateTime for virtuoso. So I replace "2099" with "2020", then I got two records.

Anyone knows the value range of xsd:dateTime in virtuoso?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Syntax issues

If this is actually your data:

```
@prefix attr: <http://my.com/attr_> .
@prefix : <http://my.com/> .
@prefix rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#> .

:t99255 attr:ts "2007-01-14 20:01:55"^^xsd:dateTime .
:t99255 attr:te "2008-10-04 14:33:09"^^xsd:dateTime .
:t99257 attr:ts "2009-05-02 04:35:11"^^xsd:dateTime .
:t99257 attr:te "2099-12-31 15:59:59"^^xsd:dateTime .
```

then you probably won't be able to load it, since it doesn't declare the `xsd:` prefix.  You might not actually be loading *any* data.  Do you get results from a query like `select * where { ?s ?p ?o }`?

### Graph name issues

> Then I load it into a graph called test

Your code, though, is

```
SELECT ?triple_0 ?t_ts ?t_te
FROM <gstest>
```

That could be a problem right there.  You might try

```
select ?g ?s ?p ?o where {
  graph ?g { ?s ?p ?o }
}
```

to make sure you've got the triples in the graphs that you expect.

### About the query and comparison

You don't need to convert the values that are already datetimes to datetimes.  I.e., instead of

```
FILTER ( xsd:dateTime(?t_ts) < xsd:dateTime(?t_te) )
```

you can do:

```
FILTER ( ?t_ts < ?t_te )
```

For instance, here's a query that binds `?t_ts`and `?t_te` to each of those date times, and returns only the ordered pairs:

```
select ?t_ts ?t_te where {
  values ?t_ts { "2007-01-14 20:01:55"^^xsd:dateTime 
                 "2008-10-04 14:33:09"^^xsd:dateTime
                 "2009-05-02 04:35:11"^^xsd:dateTime
                 "2099-12-31 15:59:59"^^xsd:dateTime }
  values ?t_te { "2007-01-14 20:01:55"^^xsd:dateTime 
                 "2008-10-04 14:33:09"^^xsd:dateTime
                 "2009-05-02 04:35:11"^^xsd:dateTime
                 "2099-12-31 15:59:59"^^xsd:dateTime }
  filter ( ?t_ts < ?t_te ) 
}
order by ?t_ts ?t_te
```

[SPARQL Results](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&query=select%20%3Ft_ts%20%3Ft_te%20where%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20values%20%3Ft_ts%20%7B%20%222007-01-14%2020%3A01%3A55%22%5E%5Exsd%3AdateTime%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%222008-10-04%2014%3A33%3A09%22%5E%5Exsd%3AdateTime%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%222009-05-02%2004%3A35%3A11%22%5E%5Exsd%3AdateTime%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%222099-12-31%2015%3A59%3A59%22%5E%5Exsd%3AdateTime%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20values%20%3Ft_te%20%7B%20%222007-01-14%2020%3A01%3A55%22%5E%5Exsd%3AdateTime%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%222008-10-04%2014%3A33%3A09%22%5E%5Exsd%3AdateTime%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%222009-05-02%2004%3A35%3A11%22%5E%5Exsd%3AdateTime%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%222099-12-31%2015%3A59%3A59%22%5E%5Exsd%3AdateTime%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20filter%20%28%20%3Ft_ts%20%3C%20%3Ft_te%20%29%20%0D%0A%7D%0D%0Aorder%20by%20%3Ft_ts%20%3Ft_te&format=text%2Fhtml&timeout=30000&debug=on)

```
t_ts                       t_te
----------------------------------------------------
2007-01-14T20:01:55+02:00  2008-10-04T14:33:09+02:00
2007-01-14T20:01:55+02:00  2009-05-02T04:35:11+02:00
2007-01-14T20:01:55+02:00  2099-12-31T15:59:59+02:00
2008-10-04T14:33:09+02:00  2009-05-02T04:35:11+02:00
2008-10-04T14:33:09+02:00  2099-12-31T15:59:59+02:00
2009-05-02T04:35:11+02:00  2099-12-31T15:59:59+02:00
```

Those are the results that I when I run that query at DBpedia, which is running an installation of Virtuoso.

Comment: Thanks very much for the answer. I tried and found that another problem may be "2099-12-31 15:59:59" may be out of range for dateTime. I update my question.